# Removing partition to install OS?

Tags: windows, linux

So i have a computer that has 2 hard drives and i installed Ubuntu server on it. I used LVM to connect the two.  So i tried to put windows back on it but it failed because it said it couldn't position the drive and then when i booted again the OS couldn't be found. So i booted it with the Ubuntu setup disc but now when it goes to partition it says that the position can not be modified because its already in use. I am asking if there is a way i can just remove everything and start fresh?

Answer (score 1):

[Gnome Partition Editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) can do just about anything you want.  It can erase, resize, move, etc...

Answer (score 1):

When you start the Windows installation, you can press `Shift + F10` to bring up a command prompt.  From there, you should be able to start `DISKPART`.  Once there, type `LIST DISK` to list all drives connected to your computer.

Then, type `SELECT DISK #`, where `#` is the disk ID from the list.  You can then type `CLEAN`, which will literally clean the partition table off of the drive.  You can then use DISKPART to manually partition the drive, *or* just close the command prompt, and restart the Windows installation (the disk should show up in the list afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the LVM first because Linux might not do anything with partitions if it detects LVM. I had that problem, too. I just took a Windows XP CD and did the installation until the point where it formats the harddrive.
I'd suggest you to try that. If that doesn't work, try to do that for each of your disk while the other one is plugged off in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to boot up Ubuntu you can also use gparted. Gui version of gparted is easy to use.  Fdisk can be used

Comment: Mind filling this out?